# Setting selected TAB with a small triangle below it

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I want my tabs to show like in the image with small triangle below it.Is this possible ?If yes, then help me with some codes or documentation.

[image: image 1]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think, the following approach is the simplest one. You just need to setup the following drawable (actually, it's Android's default drawable for tabs) as a background of the tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
</selector>
```

where `tab_press`, `tab_focus` and `tab_selected` drawables would be png's (I'd prefer [9-patches](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)) with down-arrow and transparent region near it. `tab_unselected` drawable wouldn't have this arrow, but still would have same transparent region. The only thing left to do is to specify negative bottom margin for your `TabWidget`. Its value is determined by the height of the arrow (do not forget to use [density independent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) units):

[image: explanatory scheme]

Comment: Thats helped a little bit.just  decribe abot margin

Comment: See the image I've added. It should clarify my suggestion.

Comment: but on setting negative margin on tabwidget , the arrow is cuts when list view is scrolled up

Comment: I guess, it's because of the incorrect Z-order of the elements: `TabWidget` should have higher Z-order than `ListView`, i.e. it should be defined later in xml.

Answer (score 0):

tab_0_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_yourImg_selected"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_yourImg" />
</selector>


private void addTab(int resouceTabId, int drawableId,
        Class<? extends ActivityGroup> groupActivityClass)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, groupActivityClass);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + resouceTabId);

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(resouceTabId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}

//addTab(R.string.yourTabTitle, R.drawable.tab_0_info, YourGroup.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add images to layout with tabs:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dip" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="0px" />
    <ImageView 
        ....
        android:id="@+id/down_arrow_left"/>
    <ImageView 
        ....
        android:id="@+id/down_arrow_right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and add listener in your tab activity:

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if (tabId.equels("left")){
                findViewById(R.id.down_arrow_left).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.down_arrow_right).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (tabId.equels("right")){
                findViewById(R.id.down_arrow_left).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.down_arrow_right).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```