# How to put triangle shape for page in android?

Tags: android

[image]

How to Add triangle shape for activity or page change like in facebook page?

Comment: Pratishtha, you can use triangle shape image there with popup dialog and then you can use it OR you can use QuickActionDialog. But I think using image is fine, as I have did its working very well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226863/setting-selected-tab-with-a-small-triangle-below-it

Comment: Pratishtha, if you need sample code then let me know, I cant post here, because you will not get understand that;s why.

Comment: It's nothing but a PNG showing a white triangle on a transparent background... Or you could use a TextView displaying the Unicode character `\u25b2` (filled triangle up)

Comment: @pratik,please post example if you know.

Comment: @PratishthaGoriya If I post code here then, I am damn sure you will not get things understands, I must need to explain you

Comment: @PratishthaGoriya hey there????

Comment: @pratik u can post here code.

Comment: @PratishthaGoriya here I cant, because it is complex code dear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QuickAction Dialog in android [Here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) is example code .

Comment: It's not Quick action dialog.It's a fragmentation or page.I want triangle shape on page that display in above image

Comment: Pratishtha, if you need sample code then let me know, I cant post here, because you will not get understand that;s why.

Comment: @PratishthaGoriya is that triangle movable ?or static

Comment: That triangle is movable.Please see facebook app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considered about the shape

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043386/1450401)

Also this [article](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)

And simple work around ::Give your parent layout transparent background and place the triangle in center of layout  and you can achieve the position in the image

Or you can go for 9 patch images directly  :: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529798/1450401)