# Creating a Tab Arrow indicator - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i've been stuck on doing something similar to this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8TZc.jpg)

and this is what i've done so far

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCdJg.jpg)

, i need help on how to include an arrow on each time i swipe between tabs.
Thanks you.

Comment: Did you got any working solution for your approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following site may help you with little change.
[with-a-small-triangle-below-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226863/setting-selected-tab-)
Setting selected TAB with a small triangle below it

Comment: All right. Check this site:http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64728/which-way-do-arrows-point-on-a-tabbed-web-page